# How to get a leaf with minimum depth?

Tags: f#

For example ,i have a tree with such structure

```
let tr = Node(1,[Node(2,[Leaf(5)]);Node(3,[Leaf(6);Leaf(7)]);Leaf(4)])
```

How can i get a leaf with minimum depth?

Comment: Do you need code or algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let minDepthLeaf tree = 
    let rec aux (depth: int) = function
    | Leaf(_) as l -> (l, depth)
    | Node(_, children) -> children |> List.map (aux (depth+1)) |> List.minBy snd

    aux 0 tree |> fst
```

Answer (score 7):

One approach to this problem is to implement the [Breadth-First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm. The algorithm walks over a tree in "levels" so it returns the root, then all children of the root, then all children of those children and so on. You can write that as an F# function returning sequence:

```
/// Breadth-first search over a tree 
/// Takes list of initial nodes as argument
let rec breadthFirstSearch nodes = seq {
  // Return all nodes at the current level
  yield! nodes
  // Collect all children of current level
  let children = nodes |> List.collect (function
    | Leaf _ -> [] | Node(_, c) -> c)
  // Walk over all the children (next level)
  if children <> [] then
    yield! breadthFirstSearch children }
```

This is quite useful algorithm for various tree-processing tasks, so it is useful to have it. Now, to get the lowest `Leaf` you can just pick the first `Leaf` node in the sequence:

```
breadthFirstSearch [tr]
|> Seq.filter (function Leaf _ -> true | _ -> false)
|> Seq.head
```

I think this solution is nice because it implements a more useful funciton and then just uses it to solve your particular problem on three lines.